# swing issues in scala

Tags: swing, scala, scala-swing

i'm looking at some example code that is erroring out in scala 2.9.1:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame
import javax.swing.JMenuBar
import javax.swing.JButton
import javax.swing._

import com.sun.java.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel
import javax.swing.{UIManager}
object UI extends SimpleSwingApplication {   
    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(new NimbusLookAndFeel)  
}
```

error: /some/path/Cls.scala:25: error: not found: type SimpleSwingApplication

Answer (score 1, accepted):

turns out i had to run my code like so:

scala -classpath /usr/share/java/scala-swing.jar Cls.scala

the code base that was successful is:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame
import javax.swing.JMenuBar
import javax.swing.JButton
import javax.swing._
import scala.swing.SimpleSwingApplication
import scala.swing._


object UI extends SimpleSwingApplication {   
    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName())  
    def top = new MainFrame {
      title = "First Swing App"
      contents = new Button {
        text = "Click me"
      }
    }

    def main() {
        println("hi")
    }
}
```